# Show that $\mathbf{n}\times(\boldsymbol\Omega\times\mathbf{n}) = \boldsymbol\Omega$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\mathbf{n}=(\cos{\theta},\sin{\theta})$ and $\boldsymbol\Omega=(\Omega_1,\Omega_2)$ then my lecturer says that in 2D: $$\mathbf{n}\times(\boldsymbol\Omega\times\mathbf{n}) = \boldsymbol\Omega$$

but I can't seem to show this is true..

---

We have that

$$\boldsymbol\Omega\times\mathbf{n} = \begin{vmatrix}\mathbf{i}& \mathbf{j}&\mathbf{k}\\\Omega_1&\Omega_2&0\\\cos{\theta}&\sin{\theta}&0\end{vmatrix}=(\Omega_1\sin\theta - \Omega_2\cos\theta)\mathbf{k}$$

and so

$$\mathbf{n}\times(\boldsymbol\Omega\times\mathbf{n}) = \begin{vmatrix}\mathbf{i}&\mathbf{j}&\mathbf{k}\\\cos\theta&\sin\theta&0\\0&0&\Omega_1\sin\theta-\Omega_2\cos\theta\end{vmatrix}\\=\sin\theta(\Omega_1\sin\theta-\Omega_2\cos\theta)\mathbf{i}-\cos\theta(\Omega_1\sin\theta-\Omega_2\cos\theta)\mathbf{j}\\
=(\Omega_1\sin^2\theta-\Omega_2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\mathbf{i}+(\Omega_2\cos^2\theta-\Omega_1\sin\theta\cos\theta)\mathbf{j}\\
\not=\Omega_1\mathbf{i} + \Omega_2\mathbf{j}$$

what have I done wrong?

Comment: This is not true for general $\Omega$. $\mathbf n \times$ anything will be perpendicular to $\mathbf n$, so $\Omega$ has to be perpendicular to $\mathbf n$ before there is even a chance of this holding. However, when $\Omega$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf n$, since $\mathbf n$ is unital, the expression must either be $\Omega$ or $-\Omega$ since it perpendicular to $\mathbf n$, of the same length as $\Omega$, and coplanar to them both.

Comment: By applying the right-hand-rule twice to convince yourself that this particular arrange leads to $+$, not $-$. To solve it analytically as you were attempting, you need to realize that not any $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ will do. Since $\mathbf \Omega$ is normal to $\mathbf n$, it must be of the form $(A\sin \theta, -A\cos \theta)$ for some non-zero $A$.